# Calling a C++ .dll from C# throws a runtime error 

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, dll

The following line is generating a runtime error in a C# GUI:

```
int x = myclass.number_from_dll();
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

The code in C# is:

```
class myclass
{
  [DllImport("strat_gr_dll.dll", EntryPoint = "number_from_dll")]
  public static extern int number_from_dll();
}
```

The code in the C++ .dll is:

```
// This is an example of an exported function.

DLL int number_from_dll(void)
{
  return 42;
}
```

The runtime error from .NET is:

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Comment: Do you export that function with a friendly name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = x86.

Your C/C++ DLL was compiled in 32-bit mode.  But your C# program is running on a 64-bit version of Windows and will run in 64-bit mode.  That mix don't match.  Creating a 64-bit version of you DLL is another solution.  Build + Configuration Manager, Platform combo, New, x64.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much - I just spent the last 4 hours trying to track down this problem, you're a legend!